# how to set image size with dsp:valueOf on Internet Explorer 8 compatibility

Tags: html, image, internet-explorer-8, compatibility, atg

I'm playing with Oracle ATG right now, and I have issue about IE8 browser compatibility tag. Maybe you guys can help me.

I have an image source with original size : 60 x 60 , and I have this code :

```
<img alt="product" height="20" width="20" src="<dsp:valueof param="recommendedPlan.thumbnailImage.url"/>">
```

The code works perfect on chrome and IE8 below.
But the picture doesn't resize on IE8

Any idea how to make it works ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't thinkl it have something to do with ATG-Tag, try using ccs style instead of img tag attributes:

```
<img alt="product" style="height: 20px; width: 20px;" src="<dsp:valueof param="recommendedPlan.thumbnailImage.url"/>">
```